# Conditional display of field in Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a custom (i.e. View) menu based on taxonomy vocabulary, in wich each term has an image field.

So far, each term is displayed properly with its picture, but I want to know if it is possible to display only the Image field relative to currently active term, while maintaining label+link for the whole vocabulary. Result would be to have an illustrative picture in top of menu, changing according to which item is clicker.

Is there any way to do something like that directly inside the View configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

With the use of contextual filter, you can display information for the term passed as argument/ in URL.